# Call ViewModel method from View or look for another option

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, view, viewmodel

Using a ViewModel in a View in ASP.NET MVC app.
Have a dropdownlist on page and based on user selection, I need to show/hide a section. For certain options in DDL, the section is visible and for certain options the section is hidden.

For other similar features, I was able to create a property in ViewModel and call it in the View.
But in this current case, I need to pass the value of selection option and then find if it is one that needs the section hidden/visible.
Should I create a method in viewmodel and call method in view and pass the parameter of selected value? If so, then how to do that?

if that's not the way to do it then what's the recommended approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a JavaScript/Jquery function to the dropdown list's onchange event. Inside the function you can write code to show/hide sections based on the selected value in dropdown list.

Further more, if you need to call a back end service to do any validations or retrieve data, you can use Ajax techniques.

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I need to pass the selected value to a method that would return True or False.
Using your suggestion, I'd need in my jQuery to check for value. means hard-coded values in View, is that not right or am I mistaken?

Perhaps ajax is the way to go then for this.

Comment: @N.Kaufman, if your method is a server side/. Net code you have to use ajax, otherwise you can create a method in javascript and put your logic there

Comment: @N.Kaufman, if my answer helped you, could you please mark it as the solution